# Открытие файла ( .doc) C++

Tags: visual-c++, c++

Здравствуйте)
Практически решена моя задача. 
Передача файлов работает уже для расширений .txt, .lsp.
А вот с документами Word2003 проблема.
Открываю файл

```
in = fopen("D:\lab2.doc", "r");
```

А потом когда делю файл на блоки

```
b = fread(&buff[0],1,a,in);
```

в  b  записывается 0. Почему так?

Comment: Открывайте файл как двоичный (можно всегда) fopen("D:\lab2.doc", "rb");

Comment: Может fopen не отработал (допустим, файл заблокирован каким-то приложением).

И, кстати, в программе символы те же самые (обратный слеш)? Если да, то ошибка тут.

Comment: Соглашусь c @avp. Вордовские файлы бинарные, а в винде (в отличии от никсов) имеется очень строгое отличие в открытии и работе с простыми текстовыми и бинарными файлами.

Comment: сделала 


    in = fopen("D:/lab2.doc", "rb");


но не сработало, в b все равно 0

Comment: Для того, чтобы обратный слэщ ввести в строке, нужно его продублировать. Т.е. не \\, а \\\\

Comment: А чему равно in? 

     printf("%x", (unsigned) in);

Comment: @АннаХатико, Вы коды возврата **всех** функций проверяйте и при ошибке perror() вызывайте. 

Сразу сами увидите в чем причина.

Кстати, в b = fread(&buff[0],1,a,in); `a` чему равно? Может там ноль?

Comment: в in  все нормально пишет, 52ece4f8...

Comment: а в  b=0 так и есть почему-то(

Comment: Анна, переременную **a** в этом fread() проверьте.

Comment: решилась проблема частично, просто взяла другой .doc  файл, он передает, и считываются блоки хорошо, только после записи новый файл не открывается почему-то..и боюсь что там будут не буквы, а кракозябры, которые были в буфере при передаче файла..

Comment: На всякий случай уточняю, что формат .doc файла - бинарный, а именно [COM Structured Storage](http://www.rae.ru/monographs/98-3330), поэтому если в существующий файл напрямую записывать какой-нибудь текст, скорее всего формат файла "сломается". К тому же, текст в .doc хранится в юникоде. Если же записать текст в новый файл с расширением .doc, то при открытии Вордом он скорее всего будет импортирован как простой текст.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно дело в том, что у вас используется символ "\". Обычно он используется для экранирования. Например:

```
printf("Hello world");
printf("\n");//вот оно
```

попробуйте удвоить слеш и использовать бинарное чтение. т.е. вот что должно получится:

```
in = fopen("D:\\lab2.doc", "rb");
```

так же убедитесь, что файл не занят кем-то другим

Comment: что-то сейчас вообще не записывается ничего
на  fwrite ругается , если запрашиваем файл D:\\lab2.doc, да и на любой .doc уже так реагирует..
Выдает ошибку как необработанное исключение, и отправляет в ассемблер

а в буфере при считывании первого блока вот что
+  &buff[0] 0x001052A8 "РПаЎ±б" char*

Comment: а так со всеми расширениями хорошо работает, файлы .sql, .lsp, .pro, .txt, .ewb хорошо записывает

Comment: Подозреваю выход за пределы выделенной памяти. Скорее всего пишешь больше чем можно. Ищи ошибки или выкладывай часть кода, буде править всем миром.

Comment: > а в буфере при считывании первого блока вот что + &buff[0] 0x001052A8 "РПаЎ±б" char*

Все правильно. РП (0xD0, 0xCF) - это что-то вроде сигнатуры формата COM Structured Storage. Чтобы проверить правильность работы программы, можно скачать какой-нибудь 16-ричный редактор и открыть файл в нем.